# Django limit file download

Tags: python, django, download

Is there a way to limit the speed of file downloads in django on a per user basis?
I've seen examples like the following:

```
filename = __file__ # Select your file here.                                
    wrapper = FileWrapper(file(filename))
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/plain')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return response
```

Is there any way to limit this (say premium users get full speed, basic users get a slower download)?

Comment: Ta - and what's the user auth system?

Comment: I wouldn't do it in app level. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654593/limit-apache-proxy-upload-speed-per-connection-ip

Comment: None yet but probably django.contrib.auth

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this at the server level. There are a couple of apache modules which might be able to help you acheive what you want.

http://blog.mansonthomas.com/2009/02/limit-upload-bandwith-of-your-apache.html

http://bwmod.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How would this be used to limit on a user level?

Comment: +1 Django shouldn't even being serving file downloads in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Fair enough. If Apache is the correct place to be doing this limiting then I will do it there. However, if I can't have Django limit the speed then this does not satisfy the requirements of my project.

Comment: Does it state django should be doing this explicitly? It would never be a good idea to throttle download speed through the application (massive overhead) webservers are a lot more efficient at doing things like this.